# Invoke onExit() manually in SAPUI5

Tags: manual, sapui5

Is there is a way to invoke `onExit()` Life cycle hook manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you´re talking about the `onExit` function of your controller you can! However, you should consider the View Lifecycle. According to this Lifecycle the framework will automatically call the `onExit` hook for you:

> onExit(): *Called when the view is destroyed; used to free resources and finalize activities*

*Source: [SAPUI5 Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/121b8e6337d147af9819129e428f1f75.html)*

Since it is a function which belongs to your controller you are able to call it manually by `this.onExit()` (in your controller).

**However**, this shouldn´t be necessary. To act according to the lifecycle you can call `.destroy()` of your view which destroys the view, the controller and all associated children.

> destroy(): *Cleans up the resources associated with this element and all its children.*

*Source: [SAPUI5 Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#destroy)*